# How to determine printer's postscript support using Win32 API?

Tags: c, winapi, printing, postscript

I'm developing remote printing client (native Win32 app). It simply prints files that come from server. I wish to have the ability to programmatically check if printer supports Postscript before sending data to it.

How it can be done?

GETTECHNOLOGY escape doesn't help much. Say it returns "PCL XL" for HP printers that also support Postscript.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's any way to be certain from the Win32 API that a printer is a PostScript printer,if it accepts multiple Page Description Languages.

One reason is that there is no way in PostScript to switch languages, while this *is* possible on PCL printers. So PCL/PostScript printers appear as PCL printers and allow you to switch to PostScript by sending appropriate code.

Have you tried sending POSTSCRIPT_IDENITFY ? If the driver doesn't support that then it probably isn't a PostScript driver. I'm not able to check this unfortunately.

Comment: Sad but ExtEscape() returns 0 for POSTSCRIPT_IDENTIFY for our local printer that definitely prints Postscript.

Comment: There is a distinction between a printer that supports PostScript and a PostScript printer driver. I suspect you could check the driver by iterating through the drivers dependent files and if there is a file with a .ppd extension assume it is PostScript.